# How do I stop water coming in under a level access door?

Tags: doors

When you have an outside door with level access (for wheelchairs etc), how do you stop water coming in under the door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wheelchair access needn't be completely 100% level, it just can't have steps.

It's feasible to use a door sill (such as [this](http://www.marchesironmongery.co.uk/exitex-threshex-sill-1220mm-aluminium.html)) to stop weather getting in under a door. It's also possible to have a narrow channel under the door, too, that takes rain and moisture off to the side.